# How to use Lag value of a column in condition to populate another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, time, lag

I have a table like below:

[image]

I want to create another column(Check2) with below logic:

- If Check1 ==0 then Check2 = A
- Else Check2 = Check2(lagged value) - B(lagged) - C(lagged)

Expected Output should be like below -

[image]

I have written below code but its taking very long time(in hours) for 50000 records, please help

```
for i in range(len(df)): 
            if df.loc[i,'Check1'] == 0:
                df.loc[i,'Check2'] = df.loc[i,'Volume']
            else:
                df.loc[i,'Check2'] = df.loc[i-1,'Check2'] - df.loc[i-1,'B'] -df.loc[i-1,'C']
```

Comment: Can you clear how  the `Check2(lagged value) - B - C` result is 104?

Comment: @toRex, B and C are also lagged values.. Edited now..

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for: [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) function.
It does what you want

Comment: Can you tell me how to use shift for my logic, as I dont want to lag entire column I want to do computation while using lag. I am new to python and my for loop is taking 3 hours for 100,000 records..

Comment: First of all .loc for read a scalar value is not the best solution, try to use .at 
This will give to you a good improovement, anyway i suggest to you to think a vectorial solution. 


```
<pseudocode untested>
# This for actual
mask = df['Check1'] == 0
df['Check2'][mask] = df['Volume']

# This for lagged
df['Check2'][~mask] = df[Check2'].shift(-1)[~mask] - df['B'].shift(-1)[~mask] - df['C'].shift(-1)[~mask]
```

This can be written in a better way using np.where